# How to subtract one dataframe from another?

Tags: pandas

First, let me set the stage.

I start with a `pandas` dataframe `klmn`, that looks like this:

```
In [15]: klmn
Out[15]: 
    K  L         M   N
0   0  a -1.374201  35
1   0  b  1.415697  29
2   0  a  0.233841  18
3   0  b  1.550599  30
4   0  a -0.178370  63
5   0  b -1.235956  42
6   0  a  0.088046   2
7   0  b  0.074238  84
8   1  a  0.469924  44
9   1  b  1.231064  68
10  2  a -0.979462  73
11  2  b  0.322454  97
```

Next I split `klmn` into two dataframes, `klmn0` and `klmn1`, according to the value in the 'K' column:

```
In [16]: k0 = klmn.groupby(klmn['K'] == 0)
In [17]: klmn0, klmn1 = [klmn.ix[k0.indices[tf]] for tf in (True, False)]
In [18]: klmn0, klmn1
Out[18]: 
(   K  L         M   N
0  0  a -1.374201  35
1  0  b  1.415697  29
2  0  a  0.233841  18
3  0  b  1.550599  30
4  0  a -0.178370  63
5  0  b -1.235956  42
6  0  a  0.088046   2
7  0  b  0.074238  84,
     K  L         M   N
8   1  a  0.469924  44
9   1  b  1.231064  68
10  2  a -0.979462  73
11  2  b  0.322454  97)
```

Finally, I compute the mean of the `M` column in `klmn0`, grouped by the value in the `L` column:

```
In [19]: m0 = klmn0.groupby('L')['M'].mean(); m0
Out[19]: 
L
a   -0.307671
b    0.451144
Name: M
```

Now, my question is, ***how can I subtract `m0` from the `M` column of the `klmn1` sub-dataframe, respecting the value in the `L` column?***  (By this I mean that `m0['a']` gets subtracted from the `M` column of each row in `klmn1` that has `'a'` in the `L` column, and likewise for `m0['b']`.)

One could imagine doing this in a way that replaces the the values in the `M` column of `klmn1` with the new values (after subtracting the value from `m0`).  Alternatively, one could imagine doing this in a way that leaves `klmn1` unchanged, and instead produces a new dataframe `klmn11` with an updated `M` column.  *I'm interested in both approaches.*

Comment: Incidentally, I'm unhappy with the code I used to split `klmn` into `klmn0` and `klmn1`.  Specifically, it seems cumbersome to resort to the comprehension iterating over `(True, False)` to get at the two sub-dataframes.  Is there some indexing expression `klmn[...]`, or `klmn.ix[...]`, that uses the `groupby` object `k0` directly to extract the sub-dataframes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you reset the index of your klmn1 dataframe to be that of the column L, then your dataframe will automatically align the indices with any series you subtract from it:

```
In [1]: klmn1.set_index('L')['M'] - m0
Out[1]:
L
a    0.777595
a   -0.671791
b    0.779920
b   -0.128690
Name: M
```

Answer (score 5):

Option #1:

```
df1.subtract(df2, fill_value=0)
```

Option #2:

```
df1.subtract(df2, fill_value=None)
```